# Jsonlayout with complete="True" not writing the file in correct way

Tags: java, log4j2

I have configured the log4j2 with RollingFile + Jsonlayout and compact="true" attribute and i'm rolling the log file every day.

When i run the application for first time the logs are written correctly. if i restart my application the logger misses to write "," filed between old log messages and new log messages.

How Can i Resolve This.?

```
<RollingFile name="AuditLog" fileName="D:\Logs\ASSETAudit.log" filePattern="D:\Logs\ASSETAudit-%d-%i{yyyy-MM-dd}.log" ignoreExceptions="false" immediateFlush="true">
                <Jsonlayout complete="true" compact ="true" eventEol="true" objectMessageAsJsonObject="false" includeStacktrace="false">
                </Jsonlayout>
                <Policies>
                    <TimeBasedTriggeringPolicy interval="1" modulate="true"/>
                </Policies>
            </RollingFile>
```

Due to this problem i'm unable to parse the json log file using Gson and display in web page

Comment: Please let me know any alternatives to achieve the above functionality.

Comment: Any solution for this?

Comment: @utkarsh31 : as per my knowledge no such solutions available. instead i changed the way of writing, reading log files to achieve my goal.